# Reference to a $scope array is not been updated in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.people = [
    { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo' },
    { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa' },
    { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble' },
    { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards' }
];
$scope.updateByReference = function() {
  var tst = $scope.people;
  tst = [];
  console.log($scope.people);
}
});
```

I would expect the $scope.people to have a new value of and empty array object but it's not been updated, here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/409/

Answer (score 1):

Your `$scope.people` is an object. When you do `var tst = $scope.people;`, it copies the **reference** into the `tst`. After when you do `tst = []`, it changes the `tst`'s value (which was the **reference** to the `$scope.people`, not the `$scope.people`'s value). So actually when you change the variables whole value, you only set him to refer another object.

Just do

`$scope.people = [];`

Comment: So how can I achieve the desired behaviour ?

Comment: @Petran Updated

Answer (score 0):

```
 var tst = $scope.people;  //tst reference is $scope.people.
```

Hence any change made to tst or $scope.people will reflect to both variables.

**SOLUTION:**

```
 $scope.updateByReference = function() {
      var tst = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.people));
      tst = [];
      console.log($scope.people);
    }
```